# Add child nodes to TreeView using parameters from another form in C#

Tags: c#, treeview, parent

I have a main form and a treeview on it.
I'm adding parent nodes to treeview by clicking a button.

```
        SegmentTreeView.BeginUpdate();
        SegmentTreeView.Nodes.Add(SegmentNameTextBox.Text);
        SegmentTreeView.SelectedNode = SegmentTreeView.Nodes[0];
        SegmentTreeView.ExpandAll();
        SegmentTreeView.EndUpdate();
```

I have a form -let's say FormB- that is shown by clicking a button on the main form.
There is a combobox on FormB and a button. When I clicked to 'OK' button on FormB, I need to create child nodes under the selected node of tree according to selection of combobox on FormB.
For eg, if Index0 is selected on FormB's comboBox and clicked 'OK', I have to create one child node under Parent Node that is created before. If index1 is selected, two child node and so on.

I have tried several ways. However,myForm.SegmentTreeView.SelectedNode.Nodes.Add(newNode); always returns NULL. So, it gives error while adding.

Please help to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a getter property on `FromB` that you can reference in `FormA` after `FormB` has been shown.

Example:

On `FormB`, add a getter property that looks something like this:

```
public int UserSelection
{
  get { return combobox.SelectedIndex(); }
}
```

Also make your `OK` button set the DialogResult value to OK

```
DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
```

then on `FormA`, you call the form and use it as follows:

```
private void someButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  using (FormB newForm = new FormB())
  {
    if (newForm.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
    {
      switch (newForm.UserSelection)
      {
        case 0:
          {
            // Add one node
            break;
          }
        case 1:
          {
            // Add two nodes
            break;
          }
        case 2:
          {
            // Add x nodes, etc
            break;
          }
      }
    }
  }
}
```